# Laravel in Mass Assignment is not working

Tags: laravel, foreach, variable-assignment

working on project related to category and sub-categories and works great by inserting data into the database.
But I would like to convert to laravel mass assignment that would save lots of code instead of lots of ofline code.
Most of the code works great but one section I’m trying to fix related to
Please see the sample code.

**CategoriesController.php**

```
 public function store()

    {
        $data = request()-> validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'url'=> 'required',
            'status'=>'',
        ]);
        Category::create($data);
        $levels = Category::where(['parent_id'=>0])->get();
        return view('admin.categories.add_categories')->with(compact('$levels'));
        }
```

**add_categories.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid mx-auto pt-md-5" style="width:80%;">
        <div class="card card-danger ">
            <div class="card-header ">
              <h3 class="card-title">Add Categories</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <!-- form start -->
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" name="addcategories" id="addcategories">
{{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="card-body">
<!-- Category Name -->
    <div class="form-group row">
<div class="form-group row">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">: </label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="parent_id" style="width: 220px;">
                        <option value="0">Main Category</option>
```

> ```
>                           @foreach($levels as $val)
> ```

```
                          <option value="{{ $val->id }}">{{ $val->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                 </div>
        </div>
        </div>


 </div>
              </div>
   <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-md-right ">Add</button>
        </div>
         <!-- /.card-footer -->
           </form>
</div>
    </div>
        </div>
              </div>

@endsection
```

Category.php

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

   public function scopeCategory($query)
   {
       return $query->where(['parent_id'=>0]);
   }
```

why I'm I getting the error?? I'm getting said " Undefined variable: levels (View:.." which is related to @foreach($levels as $val).... but the variable for $levels is already there...

what I'm I missing in mass assignment

please help many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You misspelled, `$levels` should be `levels` :

```
return view('admin.categories.add_categories')->with(compact('$levels'));
```

Change to :

```
return view('admin.categories.add_categories')->with(compact('levels'));
```

Or

```
return view('admin.categories.add_categories', compact('levels'));
```

Or,

```
return view('admin.categories.add_categories')->with('levels', $levels);
```

Comment: I'll add just a little correction there.
When using with() it's a good practice to do like this : 
```php
return view('admin.categories.add_categories')->with(['levels' => $levels]);`
```